# Using groovy in soapui to set the text for an xml element that is currently set to xsi:nil

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui

I am writing a groovy script which is currently using groovyUtils to update text of xml elements in my request message.  I'm having trouble updating the text of an element which has the xsi:nil attribute set.  I would like to set the text and get rid of the xsi:nil attribute.  The following script:

```
def text = '''
<list xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <technology>
        <name i:nil="true" />
    </technology>
</list>
'''

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context ) 
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(text)
holder["//name"] = "newtext"

log.info holder.xml
```

Returns:

```
<list xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <technology>
        <name i:nil="true">newtext</name>
    </technology>
</list>
```

What script should I use to get rid of the i:nil attribute.  I would like the output to be:

```
<list xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <technology>
        <name>newtext</name>
    </technology>
</list>
```

Comment: Why would you want to get rid of the i:nil attribute??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`removeAttribute(String nodeName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#removeAttribute(java.lang.String)) method as follows:

```
def text = '''
<list xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <technology>
        <name i:nil="true" />
    </technology>
</list>
'''

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context ) 
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(text)
holder["//name"] = "newtext"

def node = holder.getDomNode('//name')
node.removeAttribute('i:nil')

log.info holder.xml
```

Alternatively you can also use [`removeAttributeNS(String namespaceUri,String localName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#removeAttributeNS(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
def node = holder.getDomNode('//name')
node.removeAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance','nil')
```

This code outputs:

```
<list xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <technology>
        <name>newtext</name>
    </technology>
</list>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: That's what I was looking for. If you know where this is documented, can you post the link?  I'm having a hard time finding good documentation online.

Comment: @garrmark nice to help you. I added the links to the method api in the answer, check it out `:)`.